# oAuth with Microsoft Azure AD with azure GUEST accounts vs employee accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, adfs

I am setting up OIDC within an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web mvc application.  I have setup "OpenIdConnect" for our employees specifying the authority via

"Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0"

Where {0} is the *companyname*.onmicrosoft.com (or companyname is the tenantId) -> this works fine/well.

We have Azure GUEST accounts within our AD/ADFS and this above authority is not working for these accounts. i.e. my bob@gmail account is setup as a guest account in Azure AD.  I have read that it should against companyname.onmicrosoft.com however the only way I could log in with guest access was to use authority

"Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/**common**/v2.0"

Using **common** within the authority url I could log into my application.  This also means I had to know what type of auth employee or guest account before user could log in (i.e. different buttons making the user choose between type of auth to perform)...this is less than ideal.

I would like to use the same Authority for both employees and guest users..is this possible?

If I use  "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" > where {0} is tenant mycompany.onmicrosoft.com and try to log in with my bob@gmail AD GUEST Account it fails and I get this error... (interesting how the redirect_uri is using common even though bob@gmail is AD guest account

*This login.live.com page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=code&client_id=51483342-085c-4d86-bf88-cf50c7252078&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fcommon%2ffederation%2foauth2&state=rQIIAY2VOc_sZgGFv7lLkntJxAWlSHmlpCGS7_Vuv59EMbbHnvE6M17GdjN43_dlxhY_ACEK6jRIlClpQKmoU0Wiyy-IqCIqRAF8_AOaUz3FOdKRni-fo-_gxy9iAqeCKCIgDAAPwkmAQT7uYxAdUzgaEiEWR6D_-es3aPDJl78CH6vfvPnZy__87vUvvtq8upbZHL0LmurrzefpOLbD4_v3ZRN4ZdoM4yMBw8j7IUvqrIaSKRrGv2w23202P2w2Xz8bSIzCaEACEgcUQZI4TrxzqxOmCnymGqdRNQ6YusCwIqipbCSIkpujurqZxhV3xVALJT8RDrq7P_GFc1FGV9hhyhPvGg4sG2mpXszRMZy7mzuLmluFwiW375_9VNtOY4r-L5o-W6N_PHsVN311bZ_qfvX8x5-wMSfS6p5czlFoEqJW66unxfKdZabVC-FKaAKlnrdr4uTdyq4SPw8QAwKtS0uGuynwMRmBZanH3DQbUJwVp1nHpTRbEoN4W_BJNaFg1o6o07nP85vo7CqxuSHrrScjMriI3T7TTp1yHxTzhNeLXGDHHhZ9g_PCpNlNo7WU6D49W22BqhQ-3lRh5-b15E2mk-8H8n6jdWjB22xmU8DAl13P9nBzQlhRYqEAg7REQi2zqpNjQR4REZa1YsIJOZ74YMrmQCRsXo31sVcOR8t2q2pyd6bvWg3cna_MSNVzDkEmQKfxcCC392NnlTk_7QS0mGnMRKf9zXdEXBoV2-* ....

It is interested the reference to common here even though i was using "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" > where {0} is tenant mycompany.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: "We have Azure GUEST accounts within our AD/ADFS"?  Typically, guest accounts live in Azure AD only and are not synced from AD?

Comment: Ok thanks for correction ...any ideas about root issue? ty

Comment: COMMON -The v2.0 endpoint allows work and school accounts, but it also allows the use of personal accounts, such as hotmail.com, outlook.com, live.com, etc..

Comment: Guest users could be Azure AD users in another tenant. Is your Azure AD app. registration set up for multi-tenant? The common endpoint should then work for both.

Comment: RE: "COMMON -The v2.0 endpoint allows work and school accounts, but it also allows the use of personal accounts" > Yes I read this but my gmail account is setup as an Azure guest account within Azure AD (so I was expecting that I could use our company tenant {companyname}.onmicrosoft.com with the v2.0 endpoint INSTEAD of COMMON

hence the confusion....it is not personal account (hotmail/gmail) but a guest account using my gmail account

Comment: RE: "Is your Azure AD app. registration set up for multi-tenant? " > 

Yes, the app registration-authentication tab says my app is setup to support "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"

Comment: Got you are concern Current Azure AD B2B doesn't support guest/external users login on the common endpoint. Please refer to the [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20635231-add-support-guest-user-login-on-common-endpoint)

Comment: What error do you get when you use a guest user for authority `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/v2.0`?

Comment: When you use `common`, although you can log in with the bob@gmail account, it is not treated as guest user of your AAD. It is actually treated as a personal Microsoft account.

Comment: @AllenWu When I use https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/v2.0 > see the newly edited question above..i have now included what happens

Comment: I think the `common` endpoint is taking effect. Before you sign in, can you check it in the address bar of the browser? Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document, guests in the directory with a personal Microsoft account should work with `tenant id or contoso.onmicrosoft.com`.

Answer (score -1):

Guest users are related only to the particular tenant, so we need to give tenant id instead of common.  Current Azure AD B2B  common endpoint can't be used for guest users, guest users are treated as personal accounts.

Comment: Hmm, our company gives external users "guest accounts" to access Teams, SharePoint etc.   For clarification, when our external users log into our sharepoint with their guest account,,they are actually just logging into their personal microsoft account (and the AD guest account is some pointer to their personal msft account for the purposes of permissions/groups)

Comment: @David So the guest users log into their personal Microsoft account is what you expected?

Comment: I was expecting..that I could use the same tenant url I.e  login.microsoftonline.com{tenant id}/v2.0 for both employee logins and guest account access to my web application.  Users now must know what type of login they are using..either their employee login for employees or the  guest account for non employees.  The setup for our external users to create a msft account associated with in some cases their outside company account is already confusing.  Tell me, guest account really are just Microsoft accounts with some pointer record in AD correct?